# Excel VB code : Code works only for the first row

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code :

```
' Paste last value
    Range(Cells(LastRowP + 1, 10), Cells(LastRowP + 1, 10)).Select
    Selection.Cut
    Range(Cells(LastRowP + 1, 9), Cells(LastRowP + 1, 9)).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
```

This code should cut the content from column 10 and paste it in column 9.Unfortunately this is working only for the first entry (row 2 for example) for the other rows, it doesn't work.
Can you help?

Thank you!

Comment: LastRowP = Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
'   Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Select

Comment: the first entry in the `Range` indicates the start of the range. In your case both the start and the end of the range are the same cell (which is the last cell+1).

Comment: cut & paste is not a good solution

Comment: @loannis: Your first comment actually answers the question ;)

Comment: @SiddharthRout It does, but with minimal learning for the OP and future visitors of this thread.. And it does not address that `Select` is a bad practice in this context (hence it is a comment :) )

Comment: @loannis: I deleted my answer because of that comment :p

Comment: @SiddharthRout Please post it back, I will delete the comment. Future visitors will benefit more from an elaborate explanation rather than from a quick comment. Deleting..

Comment: @loannis: No... Don't do that. It's not right for me to post the answer. I would seriously recommend you posting an answer with all points covered :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout Oh, I can do this only later (need to go now) so  plz post back. Besides, thielemans's answer is good enough (+1) for the OP..

Comment: The problem is that my code is only taking the first row into consideration ,if for example I would write something something like:Range(Cells(LastRowP + 2, 10), Cells(LastRowP + 2, 10)).Select
    Selection.Cut
    Range(Cells(LastRowP + 2, 9), Cells(LastRowP + 2, 9)).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste  - > this would also take my second row into consideration ,is there any way I can put a range there ? so that I wont have to repeat this 20 times? I hope I'm preaty clear..this is my second week using VBA and coding overall ,so please bare with me:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
Sub CutColumn()

   LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Row
   Range("J1:J" & LastRow).Cut Destination:=Range("I1:I" & LastRow)

End Sub
```

Comment: The problem with this is,that I have a title on the first row,and buy cuting paste, I cut the title from the first row,also I have several workbooks that are running this macros.After finishing to copy the first workbook,it looks great ,but when it moves on to the second and 3rd i have the problem that this code is cutting blank cells from the previous form and pasting it over the previous data.

Comment: If you don't want to cut the title, change `J1 and I1` to `J2 and I2`. What do you mean by 2nd and 3rd is cutting blank cells?

Answer (score 0):

You are not selecting the reange correct, and you haven't mentioned the value of the LastRowP. However, if you set the FirstRowP and the LastRowP their values in the following code will work

```
Range(Cells(FirstRowP + 1, 10), Cells(LastRowP + 1, 10)).Select
Selection.Cut
Range(Cells(FirstRowP + 1, 9), Cells(LastRowP + 1, 9)).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

Comment: [INTERESTING READ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/excel-macro-avoiding-using-select)

Answer (score 0):

I think the existing answers should got you covered, but I would like to add some useful information that is relevant to your question.

First, the syntax `Range(Cells(R1,C1), Cells(R2,C2))` refers to the **square range** that starts from the cell defined by the intersection of row number `R1` and column number `C1`, till the cell defined by the intersection of row number `R2` and column number `C2` (assuming that `R1 <= R2`, else it is the other way round).

Therefore, the expressions `Range(Cells(LastRowP + 2, 10), Cells(LastRowP + 2, 10))` and `Cells(LastRowP+2,10)` are identical: they both refer to the cell that lies in the intersection of row number `LastRowP+2` (whatever that is) and column number `10`. This is the reason why your code does not work as you expect.

Having said that, there are two important elements that are considered bad practice (and from your comment to t.thielemans anwer it seems that you already discovered one :) ).

**Using Select**

The macro recorder uses `Select` a lot, and it makes it easy for someone to dive into the word of macros.. however, the macro recorder has no idea of what your intention is, and tries to stupidly replicate any action.

What is wrong with `Selection`s? First, a `Selection` returns whatever the user selects.. It can be a range, or a chart, or a sheet or whatever else... This makes it slow and error prone. The macro will fail if there is no selection, giving a run-time error. It is also slower, but for the majority of macros this is not a big issue.

In general it is not necessary to select ranges or activate worksheets in order to manipulate data. The only case I have found it necessary to activate a cell is when it is needed to programmatically add a comment to a cell. The [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/excel-macro-avoiding-using-select) that Sid mentions above shows some good ways to manipulate data without selecting/activating stuff (objects).

**Qualifying range objects**

I assume that `VBA` developers rarely use syntax like

```
Range(Cells(FirstRowP + 1, 9), Cells(LastRowP + 1, 9))
```

I myself never use it.. This code is looking for trouble :)

Both `Range` and `Cells` (and also `Columns` or `Rows` etc ) are **shortcuts**. when the above code is placed in a `VBA module`, it is interpreted as the `Range` and `Cells` of whichever sheet happens to be activated at the moment. In other words, the compiler understands `Range = ActiveSheet.Range` and `Cells = ActiveSheet.Cells`. Code like `Range("A1")` will probably work "OK" when called from something attached to a worksheet (such as button), because the `ActiveSheet` will be the `Sheet` that we refer to.. It will still cause trouble if the macro activates another sheet and then tries to refer to the range of the initial sheet (that is why it will *probably* work "OK"). And it will cause errors when it is called from a shortcut key, a userform etc.

To add to the confusion, if the exact same piece of code is placed in a worksheet module, then `Range` and `Cells` are interpreted as belonging to that worksheet.. How cool is that? :)

In order to avoid such problems, I personally qualify all objects.. An exception is when the range is `Named` (check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6228087/excel-named-range-with-vba) for example), then we can refer to it just fine (unless we are in the case below!).

Now, the qualification subtleties carry over across workbooks.. So `Sheet1.Range("A1")` implies `ActiveWorkbook.Sheet1.Range("A1")`. If we activate a different workbook, `Sheet1.Range("A1")` will refer to the range of that workbook. If two named ranges of different workbooks have the same name, then we need to qualify them as well.

To wrap up, avoiding `Select`ions and fully qualifying objects will save you from a lot of errors and trouble.

I hope this helps!